# Web services and JSON Parsing

Tags: iphone, jsonp

In my app Web services are created in dot net and i am consuming those and 
I am getting response.In that all the fields like company,type,location everything are strings  and there is no problem with this..And there is one more field called Exhibit number actually it is a Integer but they are created as string only.While I am displaying this it is showing null instead of that number..

Comment: put ur code here so that we may see it

Comment: when you retrieve just retrieve with like [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[your_dictionary ValueForKey]intValue]];